# Clevo w240aeu + Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 No Bluetooth Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, intel, centrino

I'm sorry for opening another thread about the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 but after googling I couldn't find an answer.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.13 on my laptop. I can't get the bluetooth to run at all, I had windows 7 before this and it worked fine.  The wifi works flawlessly out of the box but no matter what I do bluetooth isn't detected.  If I go into "software and updates" and click "additional drivers" nothing comes up.  If I use the hotkey "fn+f12" nothing comes up either, if I go into the bluetooth option in settings everything is grayed out.  Ill provide some logs to help, if you need any others please let me know.

Thank you.

> $ lspci | grep Centrino
>   `02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)`
>
> lsmod | egrep 'iwl|blue'
>   `bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
>   iwldvm                232285  0 
>   mac80211              630669  1 iwldvm
>   iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm
>   cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm`
>
> dmesg | egrep -i 'iwl|blue
>   `[    4.131864] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
>   [    4.131916] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
>   [    4.154517] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
>   [    4.191584] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
>   [    4.191585] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
>   [    4.191586] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
>   [    4.191588] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235 AGN, REV=0xB0
>   [    4.191653] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
>   [    4.213127] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
>   [    4.310786] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
>   [    4.310804] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
>   [    4.310811] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
>   [    4.310814] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
>   [    4.310818] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
>   [    4.315368] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
>   [    4.315376] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
>   [    4.315381] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
>   [    4.318228] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
>   [    4.318231] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
>   [    4.318239] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
>   [    4.513644] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
>   [    4.520657] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
>   [    4.795151] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
>   [    4.802175] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
>   [ 1082.160208] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
>   [ 1082.160368] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1082.160411] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1082.160539] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1082.160547] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1082.160554] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1082.160562] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1082.160573] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1082.160642] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1082.160820] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx flush command to flush out all frames
>   [ 1082.160838] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx flush command to flush out all frames
>   [ 1082.160846] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx flush command to flush out all frames
>   [ 1082.160850] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx flush command to flush out all frames
>   [ 1082.160857] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx flush command to flush out all frames
>   [ 1082.160865] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx flush command to flush out all frames
>   [ 1082.160869] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx flush command to flush out all frames
>   [ 1082.186786] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1082.186799] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1083.670028] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
>   [ 1083.670950] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
>   [ 1083.678041] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
>   [ 1086.764310] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
>   [ 1086.794657] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1086.794665] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not sending command - RF KILL
>   [ 1097.806343] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
>   [ 1097.808673] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
>   [ 1097.815793] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0`

Comment: Add the results of `lsusb` to your question.  It is odd that btusb didn't show up in the `lsmod` results

Comment: $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate >Matching Hub
`Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: I was expecting to see a device with ID 8087:07da from the lsusb.  I don't know why Linux can't find these devices on all computers but it does happen, and I don't know how to fix

Comment: I would file a bug report on ubuntu, you can start here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug

Comment: I submitted a bug.  The only thing is there wasn't a place for me to explain the issue.  Hope it helps get to the bottom of this.